# How to make a console error when a site tries to change the location?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I need to make a console error after this commands:

```js
location = 'http://example.com/';
location.href = 'http://example.com/';
```

So there will be no redirect after that.

It is about the `location` object. No need `onbeforeunload` because it is a workaround (which I know) and because I need to know/see (as a variant, in `console`) the target url without/before redirecting, `onbeforeunload` can't help with this.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243113/discussion-on-question-by-oleedd-how-to-make-a-console-error-when-a-site-tries-t).

Answer (score -2):

You can try this (it will be some like this)

```
const link = doc.getElementById("linkid"); // link
// link click event
link.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    
    try {
    // when target changed
    if (link.href !== "your location" // (or default target)) {
        e.preventDefault(); // stops routing
        console.log(link.href); // watching navigation
     } else {// console.log(link.href)}
    }
    catch(err) {
    console.err(err.message); // displaying error message 
    alert("Error: " + err.message);
    throw err;
    }
  })
```

Comment: This clearly doesn't answer the question; if you read the question the OP wants to throw an error when the `location` or `location.href` is changed, not when a link is clicked. Besides that, `getelbyid` and `addevlistnr` are not functions.

Comment: Also `click` is not an event.

Comment: @Hikmet You talk about simple things. The final goal is to get the target link before redirecting. **It is about a script link, not about an html element link** (which is extremely easy to get). An error in `console` can point where it redirects in the code.